How to wait till all geocode requests (geocoder.geocode.then()) for address is completed?
In Angular Application, I have an array with list of addresses arrayToupdate.. for the complete list, I am making a geocoder.geocode api passing the address. Our aim is to get the lat and lng for all the addresses in the array.. After the entire geoCode calls are completed, I need to make another call to update these lat and lng for the list we got LatLngUpdated
In the below code, how can we call updateGeoCodes() function after all the geocode apis are completed?
arrayToupdate = []
LatLngUpdated = []
getLatLng() {
  this.arrayToupdate.forEach((ele, index) => {
    let address = `${ele.addressLine1 || ''}  ${ele.addressLine2 || ''} ${ele.addressLine3 || ''}     ${ele.addressLine4 || ''} ${ele.city || ''} ${ele.state || ''} ${ele.postalCode || ''}`;
    if (address !== null) {
      this.geocode({ address: address }, ele.ID);
    }
  })
}
updateGeoCodes() {
  let res = this.service.updateLatLongBulk(this.LatLngUpdated)
  res.subscribe(data => {
  },
    error => {
    });
}
geocode(request: google.maps.GeocoderRequest, ID) {
  this.geocoder
    .geocode(request)
    .then((result) => {
      const { results } = result;
      const location = {
        lat: results[0].geometry.location.lat().toString(),
        lng: results[0].geometry.location.lng().toString(),
        ID: ID
      }
      this.LatLngUpdated.push(location);
    })
    .catch((e) => {
    });
}

In the mentioned code, how can we call updateGeoCodes() function after all the geocode apis are completed?

You need to use Promise.all to execute an array of promises in parallel. Then once it's completed, we can call the function in the then block, after all the promises are completed.
arrayToupdate = [];
LatLngUpdated = [];
getLatLng() {
  const promisesArr$: Array<any> = [];
  this.arrayToupdate.forEach((ele, index) => {
    let address = `${ele.addressLine1 || ''}  ${ele.addressLine2 || ''} ${
      ele.addressLine3 || ''
    }     ${ele.addressLine4 || ''} ${ele.city || ''} ${ele.state || ''} ${
      ele.postalCode || ''
    }`;
    if (address !== null) {
      promisesArr$.push(this.geocode({ address: address }, ele.ID));
    }
  });
  Promise.all(promisesArr$)
    .then((results: Array<any>, index: number) => {
      const ID = this.arrayToupdate[index].ID;
      results.forEach((result) => {
        const { results } = result;
        const location = {
          lat: results[0].geometry.location.lat().toString(),
          lng: results[0].geometry.location.lng().toString(),
          ID: ID,
        };
        this.LatLngUpdated.push(location);
      });
      this.updateGeoCodes();
    })
    .catch((e) => {});
}
updateGeoCodes() {
  let res = this.service.updateLatLongBulk(this.LatLngUpdated);
  res.subscribe(
    (data) => {},
    (error) => {}
  );
}
geocode(request: google.maps.GeocoderRequest, ID) {
  return this.geocoder.geocode(request);
}

